# 502 Bad Gateway laravel5.7

Tags: homestead, laravel-5.7

I've been using laravel homestead for quite sometime . However the last time I created a project I got this error with the latest vagrant and laravel homestead

I've tried changing the php version as most forums with the same problem but to no avial

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.15.6

Answer (score 2):

Can you add your homestead.yaml to your question?

I know you have said you've tried changing the PHP version. I'm unable to comment because of reputation so I'll answer with the typical fix for this issue below.

Had the same issue with the latest version of homestead.

There's an issue with xdebug that the homestead developers are waiting for a fix for. The solution is to disable xdebug or use php 7.2. I opted for the latter. In that case, make the following change in your homestead.yaml and then running `vagrant reload --provision` will fix this.

```
sites:
- map: homestead.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/public
  php: "7.2"
```

Comment: Thanks , let me guess a php7.3 confusion?

Comment: An issue with xdebug and php7.3, yes. Homestead developers are waiting for an upstream fix.

Comment: I'm getting quite annoyed with the people behind Homestead. Pretty much every release the past year has been broken due to the developers want to be on the bleeding edge of all software. I don't mind crashing every once in a while, but this is just stuff that should never ever pass any QA test. Clean install? Broken. Anyway. Thanks for the solution, worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it as follows:

`vagrant ssh`

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ cd /var/log/nginx`

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ ls`

access.log  error.log  **{your-site-map-name}-error.log**

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ cat {your-site-map-name}-error.log`

When you get this error:

connect () to unix: /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock failed

then you can fix it so:

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ php -v`

or

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ cd /var/run/php/`

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ ls`

You wil get you file version, my is 8.1:

php8.1-fpm.pid **php8.1-fpm.sock** php-fpm.sock

Then you need to go:

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ sudo nano {your-site-map-name}.test`

Change it in this file {your-site-map-name} .test:

`fastcgi_pass unix: /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;`

Or on a different one that you got.

Then you need only restart nginx:

`vagrant @ homestead: ~ $ sudo service nginx restart`

and should be working.